# Asychronous issue with module - Titanium

Tags: asynchronous, titanium, commonjs

I am trying to create modules(mapview,network,geolocations etc) and I face the asynchronous issue. For example I have the geolocation.js:

```
exports.getLocation = function(){

var lat="";
var lon="";
```

// Ask the user for permission to use the current location service

```
Ti.Geolocation.purpose = "Receive User Location";

Titanium.Geolocation.accuracy = Titanium.Geolocation.ACCURACY_BEST;

Titanium.Geolocation.distanceFilter = 10;
```

// Get current location (fire once)

Titanium.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(e){

```
    if (e.error){
                    alert('The device cannot get your current location');
                    return;
                }
        var longitude = e.coords.longitude;
        var latitude = e.coords.latitude;
        lon = longitude; lat = longitude;
  });

  // I WANT HERE TO RETURN LAT+LON VALUES
 // return lat+lon;
```

}

I want to call from my app.js: var location = require('/geolocation'); var latlon= location.getLocation();
but getCurrent position is asynchronous so when I use "return lat+lon" I get null. I tried callback but they cant return the value for getLocation. Is any general way to manage this asynchronous functions?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need a callback for this kind of function:

```
Titanium.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(p) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(p));
});
```